# SQL Server Full Text Search - contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

I have a really long filename stored in the database (the file name) with the full path: `C:\folder\folder\my_supper_file_name_right_here.docx`

If I use traditional

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Name LIKE '%file%'
```

I will get all the results where the file name has in the name the word `file`

If I use

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'file')
```

I get nothing

The catalog is created, the index as well and is populated.

Is my CONTAINS query wrong?

Comment: Full text search works with words. It's not a wildcard search, it's the same kind of search used in StackOverflow, Google, Bing. `C:\folder\folder\my_supper_file_name_right_here.docx` is a single item as far as full text search is concerned.

Comment: what about FREETEXT ?

Answer (score 0):

Using this way will solve your problem.

```sql
DECLARE @STR AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @STR = '"'+@STR +'*"'

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE (CONTAINS(Name, @STR))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).